# How long does it take for an application update to be approved?

Tags: updates, application-development, application-submission

I published my first application for Ubuntu recently, a commercial encryption application costing $2.99. It's somewhat simple, and consists of one .exe file (written in C# mono) and one text file.

When I published it the first time, the whole review process took about 4-5 days. However, I discovered a bug and submitted an update to fix it, also changing the title, description, version number and a few other details, it has now been 13 days and I have received no feedback.

Is this normal? How long should I expect to wait?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not normal, per se. Application updates are not given as high of a priority as new submissions and due to the higher volumes we are a bit behind in the QA process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. They probably should,  especially given the ridiculous volume of magazines lately.

Comment: It is expected that bugs are worked out BEFORE submission. Updates take just as much time as a new package and the same amount of resources, too.

Comment: In that case you guys will be in big, big trouble if ubuntu ever goes mainstream.

Comment: @trampster that will be a great problem to have (and we're planning for it, too).